# Can I subscribe to an SseEmitter in Java

Tags: java, spring, client

I am working on a Spring project in Java. We need ServerSentEvents there and using the SseEmitter looks like an easy way to send events to clients.

We also need to implement the Client in Java. Every tutorial I can find shows how to subscribe to the emitter in Javascript and the SseEmitter does not seem to have any subscription method. Does anyone know how I can listen to incoming events in Java?

Answer (score 0):

There's `ReactiveTypeHandler.SseEmitterSubscriber` which looks promising. Can't figure out how to use it though!

There are some clues in this tutorial: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-server-sent-events

Okhttp3 also has an sse consumer library, though there's scant documentation on how to use it: https://github.com/launchdarkly/okhttp-eventsource

Answer (score 0):

Totally forgot about this, I found a solution. You can just receive the emitter as a Flux and subscribe to it in your client project. There you can handle the ServerSentEvents.
So actually pretty easy but it's confusing to not receive the same thing you sent on the other side.

Comment: Do you have a code sample by any chance. I've run into the same issue

Comment: `public Flux<ServerSentEvent<String>> subscribe() {

  ParameterizedTypeReference<ServerSentEvent<String>> type = new ParameterizedTypeReference<ServerSentEvent<String>>() {
  };

  Flux<ServerSentEvent<String>> eventStream = sendGetRequest("/SseEmitter/" + userName).bodyToFlux(type);

  return eventStream;
 }`  This is how the Request looked like to receive the SSE-Emitter

Comment: `public static boolean subscribeToServer() {

   ParameterizedTypeReference<ServerSentEvent<String>> type 
   = new ParameterizedTypeReference<ServerSentEvent<String>>() {};
      
   eventStream = RequestService.getInstance().subscribe();

   if (eventStream != null) {
          eventStream.subscribe(
            content -> {GuiMessenger.handleEvent(content);},
            error -> {GuiMessenger.handleEventError(error);});
          return true;
   }
   else {
    return false;
   }
 }` Here is where I set the handling for incoming events. Hope this helps.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed! Thank you! In kotlin I got it working it like this: ```webClient.get().uri(...).retrieve().bodyToFlux(type).subscribe { ... }```